# How to install or change MySQL to use function 'load_file' by any network user?

Tags: mysql

**Goal**

Current goal is, to insert a file attachment into MySQL database as `BLOB` data from any network user. That can be from any folder - such as; Desktop.

**Problem**

This is the only path ---`C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads`--- that allows to use `load_file()` function in MySQL properly . If I try to use this path here: ---`C:/Users/eduards/Desktop`--- values show as `null`.

**Working MySQL query**

`insert into document_control (fileattachment) values (load_file('C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/test.docx'));`

value shows as `BLOB`

**Non-Working MySQL query**

`insert into document_control (fileattachment) values (load_file('C:/Users/eduards/Desktop/test.docx'));`

value shows as `null`

**Question**

If I need to uninstall MySQL - I am happy to do so. But where can I allow or enable for any file attachments from any path to be inserted as `BLOB` not as `null` - into MySQL database?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file):

> Reads the file and returns the file contents as a string. To use this
>   function, the file must be located on the server host, you must
>   specify the full path name to the file, and you must have the FILE
>   privilege. The file must be readable by the server and its size less
>   than max_allowed_packet bytes. If the secure_file_priv system variable
>   is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be
>   located in that directory. **(Prior to MySQL 8.0.17, the file must be
>   readable by all, not just readable by the server.)**
>
> **If the file does not exist or cannot be read because one of the
>   preceding conditions is not satisfied, the function returns NULL.**